# NumPy Speeding up array search and merge operations

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have three arrays, an `arr` of id's, a `range` array, and a `query` array. `arr` and `query` are very large.

Some of the values in `query` are present in the `arr` and some are not. Similarly, some of the values in `query` are within the `range` and some are not.

The data for the values in `query` that exists in `arr` comes from source **A**, and for those that do not exist in `arr` comes from source **B**. Then I merge them together keeping the original order same as the `query`. For example, in the code below, the data for value 15 should be at index 1 in the `result` array since 15 is at index 1 in the `query`. And the same goes for the `range` too.

I have a very simple code:

```
arr = np.array([1,7,3,9,5,10,2,8,4,6])
range = np.array([2,6])
query = np.array([3,15,6,8,13,5,19])

contains     = []; contains_idx     = []
not_contains = []; not_contains_idx = []
in_range     = []; in_range_idx     = []
not_in_range = []; not_in_range_idx = []
contains_mask = np.full(len(query), False)
range_mask = np.full(len(query), False)

for idx,x in enumerate(query):
    if x in arr:
        contains.append(x)
        contains_idx.append(idx)
        contains_mask[idx] = True
    else:
        not_contains.append(x)
        not_contains_idx.append(idx)
    if x >= range[0] and x <= range[1]:
        in_range.append(x)
        in_range_idx.append(idx)
        range_mask[idx] = True
    else:
        not_in_range.append(x)
        not_in_range_idx.append(idx)

result = np.zeros((len(query), 5)) # 5 dimensions, n x 5 array.
# Now I get the data for the values in contains and not_contains arrays.
# For simplicity, I am generating random data here.
data_for_contains = np.random.random((len(contains), 5))
data_for_not_contains = np.random.random((len(not_contains), 5))
# Put the acquired data in the result array, keeping the same order as query.
result[contains_idx] = data_for_contains
result[not_contains_idx] = data_for_not_contains
# The same operations are carried out to generate result for the in_range and not_in_range arrays.
# Some other operations are carried out on the mask arrays, omitted here.
```

Since the `arr` is extremely large, and `query` is also very large (though smaller than `arr`), this code is slow. Is there any way to optimize it for speed and performance?

Also, can this be sped up using GPU?

Comment: you shouldn't overwrite the builtin [range](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range), also ```mask``` isn't defined

Comment: _the data for the values in query that exists in arr comes from source A, and for those that do not exist in arr comes from source B_ - then why are they in the same array?

Comment: Broadly this should not use enumerate or any loop, and should use `np.isin`. But until you show reproducible code (with a constant random seed!) an answer is not practical.

Comment: @Reinderien, Both the mask arrays (`contains_mask` and `range_mask`) are defined and are Boolean arrays of the same size as `query. The values are in the same array because that is how they are received.

Comment: How large are `arr` and `query`? Will they all fit in memory, including masks and indexes?

Comment: Is this calculation done only once for each input? If `arr` are the IDs of something that might exist in source A, aren't these things that are used repeatedly, like a database?

Comment: @ken, `arr` and `query` are very large but so is the memory, so they can fit in the memory. And these operations on `query` are done almost half a million times. And both the `arr` and `query` contains unique values.

Comment: What I was wondering is that if `arr` does not change for these millions of operations (or changes only once every few hundred operations), then we can pre-convert `arr` into a form that is more suitable for searching. For example, @Reinderien's answer would be several times faster if the `arr` was pre-sorted. Of course, sorting `arr` is time consuming. But if `arr` is used repeatedly, there would be enough benefit to get it back.

Comment: @ken, `arr` is fixed and does not change. If pre-sorting it can speed up the operations then by all means, we can sort it. Then how to adapt @Reinderien's answer to pre-sorted `arr` as you suggested?

Comment: Nothing special. Just add `arr = np.sort(arr)` after initializing `arr`. If `arr` is shuffled as in your example, this will make it faster. Also, none of your operations care about the order of `arr`, so this will not change the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python [Set](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) to accelerate the process of **`x in s`**.

A Python Set is implemented as a **hash map** thus [the average time complexity of `x in s` operation is **`O(1)`**](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity), which is significantly faster than `in` operation of a NumPy array which is `O(N)`.

---

I can show you some simple experiments:

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(10000)
query = np.random.rand(10000)
```

This is a simplified version of your code:

```py
def naive_find_if_exists(arr, query):
    indices = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(query):
        if item in arr:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
```

```py
%timeit naive_find_if_exists(arr, query)
23.9 ms ± 153 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**An optimized version using Python Set**:

```py
arr_set = set(arr)
def better_find_if_exists(arr, query):
    indices = []
    for idx, item in enumerate(query):
        if item in arr_set:
            indices.append(idx)
    return indices
```

```py
%timeit better_find_if_exists(arr, query)
691 µs ± 4.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

From 23.9ms to 691us, that's a **34.5x** performance improvement.

Comment: Using the set approach, can I get the indices at which the values exists in `arr`? For example, in the above code, can I get the indices as [2,9,7,4] which are the `arr` indices of `query` items [3,6,8,5] that exists in `arr`?

Comment: And how to speed it up for `range`?

Answer (score 0):

Don't loop.

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.array((1, 7, 3, 9, 5, 10, 2, 8, 4, 6))
range_lo, range_hi = 2, 6
query = np.array((3, 15, 6, 8, 13, 5, 19))


np.random.seed(0)

contains_mask = np.isin(query, arr)
n_contained = np.count_nonzero(contains_mask)
data_for_contains = np.random.random((n_contained, 5))
data_for_not_contains = np.random.random((contains_mask.size - n_contained, 5))
contains_result = np.empty((len(query), 5))
contains_result[contains_mask] = data_for_contains
contains_result[~contains_mask] = data_for_not_contains

assert np.array_equal(
    contains_mask,
    ( True, False,  True,  True, False,  True, False),
)
assert np.allclose(
    contains_result,
    np.array([
       [0.5488135 , 0.71518937, 0.60276338, 0.54488318, 0.4236548 ],
       [0.97861834, 0.79915856, 0.46147936, 0.78052918, 0.11827443],
       [0.64589411, 0.43758721, 0.891773  , 0.96366276, 0.38344152],
       [0.79172504, 0.52889492, 0.56804456, 0.92559664, 0.07103606],
       [0.63992102, 0.14335329, 0.94466892, 0.52184832, 0.41466194],
       [0.0871293 , 0.0202184 , 0.83261985, 0.77815675, 0.87001215],
       [0.26455561, 0.77423369, 0.45615033, 0.56843395, 0.0187898 ],
    ])
)

range_mask = (query >= range_lo) & (query <= range_hi)
n_in_range = np.count_nonzero(range_mask)
data_for_range = np.random.random((n_in_range, 5))
data_for_not_range = np.random.random((range_mask.size - n_in_range, 5))
range_result = np.empty((len(query), 5))
range_result[range_mask] = data_for_range
range_result[~range_mask] = data_for_not_range

assert np.array_equal(
    range_mask,
    (True, False,  True, False, False,  True, False),
)
assert np.allclose(
    range_result,
    [[0.6176355 , 0.61209572, 0.616934  , 0.94374808, 0.6818203 ],
       [0.57019677, 0.43860151, 0.98837384, 0.10204481, 0.20887676],
       [0.3595079 , 0.43703195, 0.6976312 , 0.06022547, 0.66676672],
       [0.16130952, 0.65310833, 0.2532916 , 0.46631077, 0.24442559],
       [0.15896958, 0.11037514, 0.65632959, 0.13818295, 0.19658236],
       [0.67063787, 0.21038256, 0.1289263 , 0.31542835, 0.36371077],
       [0.36872517, 0.82099323, 0.09710128, 0.83794491, 0.09609841]]
)
```